# how to redirect the logging output of xmlrpc server to some file

Tags: python, logging, xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver

I'm using the SimpleXMLRPCServer module to create a rpc server. Whenever i send any request to server it shows me the connection request. How can i redirect this output to some file so that i can see the request made to the server later.

this is my script for server

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
import logging
import os
import string
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE 
import xmlrpclib
# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename = 'RPCServer.log')
class FileOperation():
'''Class to perform file operation on the Remote machine'''
    def __init__(self):
       self.fh = None
       self.os = os            #adding built-in OS module functionality
       self.string = string    #adding built-in String module functionality

# Restrict to a particular path.

class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)
# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000), requestHandler = RequestHandler,allow_none = True, logRequests = True)
server.register_introspection_functions()
server.register_instance(FileOperation(),allow_dotted_names = True )


# Run the server's main loop
try:
    print 'Use Control-C to exit'
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Exiting'
```

Whenever I send any request I'll get o/p like this -

```
Use Control-C to exit
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:29] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:30] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:31] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:32] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:33] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:34] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 11:34:35] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

How can i redirect this o/p to some file. I set the file name in logging config but the o/p doesn't go there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The messages are written to `sys.stderr`. You can either

1. Redirect `stderr`, or
2. In your subclass of `SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler` override the method `log_message` and use `logging` there if you wish.

The original method is `BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message` in module `BaseHTTPServer` and looks like this:

```
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    """Log an arbitrary message.

    This is used by all other logging functions.  Override
    it if you have specific logging wishes.

    The first argument, FORMAT, is a format string for the
    message to be logged.  If the format string contains
    any % escapes requiring parameters, they should be
    specified as subsequent arguments (it's just like
    printf!).

    The client host and current date/time are prefixed to
    every message.

    """

    sys.stderr.write("%s - - [%s] %s\n" %
                     (self.address_string(),
                      self.log_date_time_string(),
                      format%args))
```